# Relogging a user in with different Spring Security Authorities programmatically

Tags: spring-security

**PreReq:**
User logs in and is given roles got from the database using a custom implementation of userService. i.e.

> authentication-provider user-service-ref="securityPolicyService"

The implemented method *loadUserByUsername* gets called and the roles are load for the user for the particular club they are logging into, Default one is loaded first time in.

The user then click on a different club from the UI and I call a method on a service that gets the new list of authorities for this club.

I then perform the following:

```
Object principle = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
SecureMember sm = (SecureMember) principle;
Authentication auth = 
      new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(sm, null, newAuthories); <br><br>
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);<br>
request.getSession(false).invalidate();
```

SecureMember extends User from SpringFramework.

The problem is the SecureMember authorities are never updated with the new ones.

thanks
Gary

Comment: why are you invalidating the session? isn't the user getting logged out when you do that?

Comment: sorry, request.getSession(false).invalidate(); is called before the above snipped. It should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security won't store the security context if the `HttpSession` is null and was invalidated during the request, so if you set the context after invalidating the session (and don't create a new session), then it won't be stored.

You should see [this log message](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java#L305) if this is the case (and you have debug logging enabled).

Either create a new session or don't invalidate the original one.